# Google Cloud Platform: Remove the firewall rule that allowed traffic to all of the instances

Tags: networking, firewall, vps, google-cloud

What does this mean in practical terms?

> Firewall rules are only "allow" rules. You cannot create "deny" rules.
>   If you need to restrict traffic from reaching certain instances,
>   create rules that allow traffic to the other instances, then remove
>   the firewall rule that allowed traffic to all of the instances.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-ip-addresses

I want to restrict traffic to a few specified IP addresses and ports.  The logic is to create rules allowing each specified IP address and then what?  Remove the firewall rule that allowed traffic to all of the instances?

**Which** firewall rule is that?

*(I would much rather run mail-in-a-box with fail2ban but apparently MIAB cannot cope with port 25 getting throttled or blocked.)*

Comment: The text is referring to the  firewall rules of Google own provisioning interface and not to the local `iptables` rules of your own servers.